# How to identify a predator's coprolite from an herbivore's?

Tags: rocks, paleontology, fossils

I have a coprolite that is 8" by 5" and weighs 8 lbs. The shape is similar to a lumpy brain, the colors below outer crust are deep red and the crust is pastel green and grey. It has a strong density and can't be chipped with a hammer. It came from the Grand Canyon.

Here are some pics:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Maybe chemically? But I can't access this: http://www.jstor.org/stable/41762787?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents

Comment: BTW This may help as well http://meta.earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/124/a-guide-for-asking-identify-this-rock-questions

Comment: I also need help to narrow down 3 meteorite candidates, all 3 have every charistic of a meteorite. I need verification of a suspected  raw orange vietnam opal and proposed petrified wood specimen.Thanks I will link them all soon to this forum.

Comment: BTW There is also https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:Unidentified_rocks_and_minerals

Answer (score 3):

If it is a predator's coprolite you should expect to see bone fragments. Coprolites from herbivores? I would expect them to be pretty rare as there is almost nothing likely to fossilize.
As for meteorites, they come in many forms: stones, irons, palasites, chondrites. The candidates need a good description. A weathered heat ablation surface is the most obvious characteristic to look for. In all cases the rock identification is best achieved with a polarizing microscope, unless it is something very obvious like an iron meteorite.